# Inflating Spinner into main Layout

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

In my Main Activity I have two tabs,for two tabs two different layouts are used. In one tab I have spinner. I am setting a list in the main activity for spinner but its showing `NullPointerException`.

this is my code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> presAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            presAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            MyList.setAdapter(presAdapter);
```

Comment: what are the values in `list`

Comment: MyList might be null have you referenced it ie MyList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourspinnerid);

Answer (score 0):

Do you habe Problems fill datas to spinner?

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner() 
  {      
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(this.getString(R.string.x));
    list.add(this.getString(R.string.y));
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }
```

Im using this, may it helps :)

Comment: Its showing null pointer exception at spinner.setAdapter @oli

Comment: do you have set the varaible ? `private Spinner spinner1;`

Comment: Is the spinner in your layout with id spinner1?

Comment: check your class, theres missing something. impoirts/oncreate layout etc

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed any 1 of the following

setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutname);

MyList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourspinnerid);

or list may be null

Comment: NO i have mention all you mentioned,but still its showing same error

Comment: you have 2 layout each with a spinner right see if you have set 1st layout and referring to the id of spinner in 2nd layout. even this is not the problem then post your full code of that class i will help you.

Comment: I have Main Activity,I have written code here to set two tabs,in one tab i have spinner, i have setting the values into that spinner through arrayAdapter but it is showing that spinner is empty.